# How to open a Julia Jupyter Qtconsole from an IJulia notebook?

Tags: julia, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ijulia-notebook

With the IPython Jupyter notebook, I use the magic `%qtconsole` to open a Qtconsole connected to the same IPython kernel as the notebook.

How does one do this with the IJulia notebook?

Answer (score 1):

To open a console:

jupyter console  --kernel=julia-0.4
jupyter console  --kernel=julia-0.6

To open a qtconsole:

jupyter qtconsole  --kernel=julia-0.4
jupyter qtconsole  --kernel=julia-0.6